# Multiple tray icons in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

We have a Java based with some native components and SWT as frontend.

We contribute our tray icon to Windows notification area.

If an user is working on the application and then the system goes to sleep/hibernate when the system wakes up it has multiple tray icons for the same application.

We have seen it happening for multiple applications. Is it a known issue or are there any workarounds ?